# Finding the minimum value of magnitude of this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

**|z|>2** then find the minimum value of "**|z+1/2|**"
How can I solve this using circles?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Cauchy-Schwarz tells us that $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ with equality iff $a$ and $b$ are colinear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy=|z|e^{i\theta}$ with $|z|>2$ and let $w=u+iv=|w|e^{i\phi}$ with $|w|=\frac12$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
|z+w|&=\sqrt{(z+w)(z^*+w^*)}\\
&=\sqrt{|z|^2+|w|^2+2\text{Re}(zw^*)}\\
&=\sqrt{|z|^2+|w|^2+2\text{Re}(|z||w|e^{i(\theta - \phi)})}\\
&=\sqrt{|z|^2+|w|^2+2|z||w|\cos(\theta - \phi})\\
&=\sqrt{(|z|-|w|)^2+2|z||w|(1+\cos(\theta - \phi)})\\
&\ge||z|-|w||\\
&>\frac32
\end{align}$$

with the minimum at $\theta - \phi = \pi$